# Linux: How do I backup my user files from the live CD?

Tags: linux, backup, grub, kernel-panic

Right, I did some updates last night and it messed up my install of KDE Neon, gave me a kernel panic error: not syncing vfs: unknown mount 0, 0 etc...

After spending all night and this morning trying to fix the vfs error, I have had no luck. I managed to mount my drive inside the live cd which I booted from and had a go at updating initramfs and grub but all it did was give me errors and for some reason grub was no where to be found anyway?

Anyway, I guess I'm going to have to accept everything is too far gone now and wish to just backup all my data and reinstall.

My problem is I want to backup certain directories such as /home/user/.config but it won't let me because of permission issues.

If I wanted to backup to my USB what can I do here?

Comment: If you run all commands as `sudo` then it should be able to give you access regardless. Mount your broken volume as read only and mount your USB as read/write and you should be able to copy everything off...

Comment: But as I'm accessing the FS from the live CD it says im not the user, so I cannot access it?

Comment: A Linux LiveCD should still be able to mount and access volumes using `sudo`...

Comment: When I try and backup the .config dir it says omitting '.config' ?

Comment: Even when using `sudo`?

Comment: Yeah `sudo cp .config /media/ubuntu/Storage` is what I use?

Comment: Try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35779/what-does-cp-omitting-directory-mean - You may be missing `-r` from your `cp` command. `-r` tells `cp` to use recursive copying and take directories.

Answer (score 0):

As taken verbatim from AskUbuntu answer "[What does "cp: omitting directory" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35779/what-does-cp-omitting-directory-mean)":

> By default, `cp` copies only the direct files in, and not subdirectories
>   in the directory. The message `cp: omitting directory 'directory'` warns
>   you that the mentioned directory is not copied.
>
> To do so, specify the `-r` (or `--recursive`) option:
>
> ```
> sudo cp -r ~/Transfers/ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal/library/Zend/* ~/public_html/cmsk.dev/library/
> ```
>
> The [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/cp.1.html) (command: `man cp`) contains an overview of the
>   available options.